# how do implement search in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, search, mkmapview

I want to implement local search and display locations on mkmapview. I know how to get current location, etc... but is there a google api for the iphone? the geo api is complex and requires loading JSON and other app delegate modules.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to implement MKMapView Search;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034118/how-to-implement-mkmapview-search)

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question a little while back, I found http://www.geonames.org/ was quite useful and returns the long and lat in an xml format. This can then be used to init a CLocation object with coordinates. An example search URL would be http://www/geonames.org/search.html?q=london

I would recommend reading Ole Begemann's comments - [How to find the long and lat of a city on the iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952980/how-to-find-the-long-and-lat-of-a-city-on-the-iphone)